# Rendering problems, could not find android.support.v4.widget.Drawerlayout

Tags: android, xml, navigation-drawer

I have tried each and every solution from the SO, but my problem still isn't solved. Following is the error I am getting:

> The following classes could not be found:
>   - android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout (Fix Build Path, Create Class)
>    Tip: Try to build the project.

I am just exporting [this android project into android studio(1.2).](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)
I have applied [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30181260/following-classes-not-found-android-support-v4-widget-drawerlayout) solution and many other , but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio's XML editor preview will give you that error whenever you use a "custom" view - be it third-party library views or Google's own `DrawerLayout`, as you've experienced yourself.

But fear not, **that error will only be shown on the XML preview, your project should compile just fine**. Go ahead and try. :)

Hope this helped!

***p.s.,*** Switching API level on the editor (as suggested by an answer here) helps fix API 22 rendering error for "normal" in-build views, but not for `DrawerLayout` or any other third-party views really.

Answer (score 1):

You Need To change the API level from 5.1.1 to 5.0.1.it is on upper right side corner in design of xml.:)